# How to consolidate multiple conftest files into one conftest in pytest?

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I have multiple `conftest.py` files in different test directories with each have slight variations.
e.g.

---

```
/test
     /test1
           conftest.py
           test_test1.py
     /test2
           conftest.py
           test_test2.py
```

Each conftest has `pytest_addoption(parser)` and `parameters(request)` fixture with differences and similarities in args. eg. 
*test1/conftest.py*

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
   parser.addoption("--a", required=True)
   parser.addoption("--b")

@pytest.fixture
def parameters(request):
   parameters = {}
   parameters["a"] = request.config.getoption("--a")
   ...
```

*test2/conftest.py*

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
   parser.addoption("--a")
   parser.addoption("--b")

@pytest.fixture
def parameters(request):
   parameters = {}
   parameters["a"] = request.config.getoption("--a")
   ...
```

Is there a way to combine these `conftest.py` files into one at the parent directory? I heard of making a fixture with scope `package` but not sure how that would work.

Comment: The location of the fixture and the scope are totally different things. Yes you can combine these files… what’s stopping you?

Comment: There comes a problem of `pytest_addoption` not having a way to pass values. If I have 10-15 args, I wanted to not have 15 `parser.addoption(arg1)....parser.addoption(arg15)`.

Comment: you could do this with a loop or something, but I still don't see a clear programming question here. from what I can tell, the answer is very clearly "yes, you can combine them" and everything about the implementation is up to you. the aesthetics of the implementation aren't [on topic](/help/on-topic) at stack overflow. But if you're running into a specific bug/snag or can't figure out how to merge two specific elements or how to implement something in pytest then feel free to ask another question. But as it's stated currently I think this question is too broad.